# How may I boot up 14.04 lts without having to worry about having a usb or cd inserted during startup?

Tags: boot, usb, bios, cd-drive

I installed via a usb thumbdrive, and before doing so I had to change boot options to boot from usb. Now upon boot, im prompted at startup to choose an os to boot from usb or boot ubuntu(which isnt a really a huge problem since i test different os's every now and then), the issue is if any type of disc is inserted i get a backlit black screen. and can litterally do nothing. I was just to the point of reinstalling windows until I popped out the disc(didnt realize one was inserted) and I had an option to exit, ubuntu started up with some bugs, so i restarted and all is fine now. Im wondering if I may change boot optiong to prevent the black screen because of a cd, but keep the ability to boot from usb, or is this a hardware issue?

Answer (score 0):

i have had this problem before. i fixed it by using the infamous boot repair disk. its a 64 bit copy but it runs on 32 bit laptop fine. here is the link. http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/ it re installs grub and fixes the crashy thingy